# Angular 2, Is there a way via eventliseners to pass all parent loops indexes?

Tags: arrays, angular, event-listener

I have a several level nested list and on onDropSuccess i would like to pass to the function onDropSuccess all parent indexes including this one that I am dropping the item on. So I would like to pass listitem, rowitem and cellitem. How to do this so I can reuse the function in all nested children?

```
<div *
ngFor="let tableitem of table; let listitem = index" 
(onDropSuccess)="onDropSuccess($event, passAllIndexAboveIncludingThisOne )"
>
 <div  *ngFor="let rowitem of tableitem.rowitem; let rowitem = index" 
(onDropSuccess)="onDropSuccess($event, passAllIndexAboveIncludingThisOne )"
>
 <div  *ngFor="let cell of rowitem.cell; let cellitem = index" 
(onDropSuccess)="onDropSuccess($event, passAllIndexAboveIncludingThisOne )" 
>

Something data here
</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. I just renamed all the indexes there was some duplication between the first variable after `let` and the variable where you affected your indexes. Then I think you can see by yourself I use standard array, to pass the variables to the function.

```
<div *ngFor="let tableitem of table; let indexItem = index" (onDropSuccess)="onDropSuccess($event, indexItem)">
  <div  *ngFor="let rowitem of tableitem.rowitem; let indexRow = index" (onDropSuccess)="onDropSuccess($event, [indexItem, indexRow])">
    <div  *ngFor="let cell of rowitem.cell; let indexCell = index" (onDropSuccess)="onDropSuccess($event, [indexItem, indexRow, indexCell] )" >
      Something data here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And you can use the `onDropSuccess` like this:

```
onDropSuccess(event, datas) {
   console.log(event, datas);
}
```